# How can you write an array with array with each element repeated numRepeats times?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on an array that returns a new array with each element repeated numRepeats times.

For example:

```
repeatElements(new String[]{"hello", "world"}, 3)
```

Should return a new array with the elements:

> ["hello", "hello", "hello", "world", "world", "world"]

This is what I got so far.

```
public String[] repeatElements(String[] array, int numRepeats)
{
   String[] copy = new String[array.length * numRepeats];  
   String[] shortName = array.split("\\s+");

   for(int i = 0; i< numRepeats; i++){
      Arrays.fill(copy, shortName[i]); 
   }

   return copy; 
}
```

Comment: Why have you written `String[] shortName = array.split("\\s+");`? That doesn't seem to bear any relation to your listed requirements. Is there something you're not telling us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] arr = {"hello", "world"};
int n = 3;
String[] newArr = new String[arr.length * n];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        newArr[(i * n) + j] = arr[i];
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
// [hello, hello, hello, world, world, world]
```

Traditional for loop would be much more easier to read in this case.

This is how I generated the index for the `newArr`: `(i * n) + j` so that it goes from `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just initialize the `copy` array and then loop through the indexes and fill it, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < numRepeats; j++){
        copy[(i * numRepeats) + j] = array[i]
    }
}
```